# Missing "passenger.conf" Apache2

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, apache2, passenger, redmine

I am trying to deploy Redmine on my Ubuntu Linux server running Apache2. However, for my deployment of Redmine, I need to modify `passenger.conf` which is missing at the path `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf`. I am wondering if this configuration file should have been provided during installation and how I can create this missing file?

Comment: @AleksandarPavić  What are you talking about? I am following the installation guide for Ubuntu Linux found on the Redmine Wiki. You do realize you can ask questions and don't have to make assumptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to configure passenger, then install using this ref link from phusion passenger official site
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/intro.html